# Getting error C2440

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
char StudentName[50];
char StudentMajor[4];
double StudentGPA;
double StudentCredits;
char StudentID[9];
};

void main()
{
struct student Student;

strcpy(Student.StudentName, "Christian Gigliotti");
strcpy(Student.StudentMajor, "TECH");
strcpy(Student.StudentGPA, "2.4");
strcpy(Student.StudentCredits, "31");
strcpy(Student.StudentID, "J02062414");

printf("Student's Name: %s\n", Student.StudentName);
printf("Student's Major: %s\n", Student.StudentMajor);
printf("Student's GPA: %d\n", Student.StudentGPA);
printf("Student's Credits Earned: %d\n", Student.StudentCredits);
printf("Student's ID: %s\n", Student.StudentID);

return 0;
}
```

I'm getting `error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'double' to 'char*'` on line 24 and 25.

I think it has something to do with the double I'm trying to use for the gpa & credits. I don't understand why it would effect those lines.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use strcpy on a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
strcpy(Student.StudentGPA, "2.4");
strcpy(Student.StudentCredits, "31");
```

since `Student.StudentGPA` and `Student.StudentCredits` are of type `double`.

Use:

```
Student.StudentGPA = 2.4;
Student.StudentCredits = 31;
```

BTW, the line

```
strcpy(Student.StudentMajor, "TECH");
```

will lead to undefined behavior since `Student.StudentMajor` doesn't have enough space to hold those characters and a terminating null character. Make the size of `Student.StudentMajor` at least 5.

```
strcpy(Student.StudentID, "J02062414");
```

suffers from the same problem.  Make the size of `Student.StudentID` at least 10.